# The process continues to increase when pyinstaller program execute

Tags: python

I make the program using pyinstaller.
I command "pyinstaller --clean -F SysTrader.spec 
But, When the program execute, process continues to increase by 1

ex> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HiVx.png)

Below, i used "SysTrader.spec" spec file.

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['SysTrader.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\OneButton_1.0.1'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\OneButton_1.0.1\\resources\\OneButton_ui.ui','./resources'), ('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\OneButton_1.0.1\\resources\\OkCancelDialog_ui.ui','./resources'), ('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\OneButton_1.0.1\\logs\\program_log','logs') , ('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\OneButton_1.0.1\\logs\\trade\\trade_log','logs\\trade')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='SysTrader',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
```

Comment: What does "process continues to increase" mean?

Comment: I edit content. Show the image